# Google translate API phrase into every language using classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, google-translate

Good morning everyone,

I have something [maybe not so] unique which I want to do which is translate a simple phrase like "Hello" into every language available under Google Translate API.  I want to basically capture the results and store it into a SQL Server database.

In the past, I have written bulk geocoding processes using ASP and that worked well, and I am thinking that I can do the same with the translate API using a querystring.  However, there are really no great examples of it.

I am about to drop the languages and their codes into a table so that I can just loop through things, and then use a JSON parser since I am not using the latest version of SQL Server.  I have done crazy ASP SOAP implementation in the past which required authentication twice, but am thinking that this can be done differently.

I am just figuring that someone else out here might have had to slay this dragon before and any and all tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Translation API only allows for [one target language per request](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions). Unfortunately, for your use case you would have to loop through the desired languages and send a separate request for each.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I got busy for the past few days (steam pipe pinhole leak) and was thinking that I would try one, and then just loop it.  I might have to mess with my PHP and CURL programming but prefer SQL Server.